# Is there any way to get the battery consumed by the android apps respectively

Tags: android

I have been trying to collect the battery consumption details corresponding to the app so that I can perform analysis over the data. But all I could find is battery stats which help to get the details. I want to show that data in the app that I am developing. So could someone suggest as how to do it